# Ошибки при работе с webview android

Tags: android, webview

Я внедряю в свое приложение виджет отображения веб-контента. Я думал что будет все просто и понятно, но оказалось что не совсем. Стали появляться ошибки которые я так и не понял почему появляються. Вот первая ошибка:

```
"Refused to display 'https://www.modis.de/de-de/Job/embedded-software-entwickler-mw-lindau/?ID=ef5d9e3f-b48b-4935-97fb-3f1eeebc720e' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.", source: about:blank (0)
```

и вот вторая ошибка:

```
"Failed to decode downloaded font: ссылка1", source: ссылка2 (0)
```

и я не могу понять в чем проблема. Вроде все подключил как нужно. Вот вебвью в xml:

```
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

и вот код в активити:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra("job_link"));
```

думал что проблема в джаваскрипте, но после его поключения ошибка не пропала. Если я правильно понимаю вторую ошибку, то она говорит что мое вью не может отобразить загруженный шрифт. Но почему тогда обычный хром на телефоне все показывает красиво. Не могу понять что я сделал не так и что нужно дописать чтобы все работало как нужно.

Comment: "Обычный" хром :D

Comment: @RomanK., уже пришел к этому выводу)))) а то webView это конечно круто, но очень много косяков каких-то странных.

Comment: Если нужно просто отобразить какую-то страницу - гляньте на CustomTabs      https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/browser/customtabs/package-summary